# Custom legend in TChart Tool

Tags: activex, teechart

Can one provide me a example for the Custom Legend Tool. I Want to Show Data in a tabular Format at the bottom of the chart. Can't use Data Table since it display the Value which are used for the drawing the chart. I want to provide some product related Data in tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool isn't still fully usable in TeeChart ActiveX as you can read [here](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=395).
Feel free to add your mail to the CC list to be automatically notified when an update arrives.

In the meanwhile, the only solution I can think on would be using custom drawing techniques: manually drawing your texts and shapes at OnAfterDraw event.